# Bootstrap - Fill fluid container between header and footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fluid-layout

This may be a very simple question, but I've been out of the CSS scene for awhile and I can't seem to figure it out. I am using the Bootstrap framework and I have a fixed header and footer. The container in between includes a navbar and content area. I would like that container to fill the entire space (100% height) in between the header and footer.

Here is jsFiddle of the project: http://jsfiddle.net/NyXkt/2/

This is the current html structure:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <!-- Header -->
    <div class="container-fluid no-padding header">
        <div class="row-fluid fill-height">
            <!-- Header Left -->
            <div class="span2">
                <p class="center-text">Left</p>
            </div>
            <!-- Header Middle -->
            <div class="span8">
                <p class="center-text">Middle</p>
            </div>
            <!-- Header Right -->
            <div class="span2">
                <p class="center-text">Right</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Content Wrapper -->
    <div class="container-fluid no-padding fill">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span2">
                <div class="well sidebar-nav-fixed no-padding">
                    <ul id="nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>

                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 a</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 b</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 c</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>

                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 a</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 b</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>

                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 a</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 b</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 c</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 d</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>

                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 a</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 b</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 c</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span10">
                <p class="center-text">Content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Footer -->
<div id="footer">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <p class="center-text">Footer</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

If anyone could explain what I may need to do, or point me to an example, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Hi, `[bootstrap]` tag it's not for the CSS framework, you should use `[twitter-bootstrap]` instead.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Bootstrap 4 (update 2019)**

Now it's easier to get this layout using flexbox.

```
<body class="d-flex flex-column">
    <header>
    </header>
    <main class="container-fluid flex-fill">
    </main>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</body>

body {
   min-height:100vh;
}

.flex-fill {
   flex:1 1 auto;
}
```

[Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/tGamlWscIB)

**Note:** The `flex-fill` utility class will be [included in the next Bootstrap 4.1](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/2137d61eacbd962ea41e16a492da8b1d1597d3d9) release. So after that release the extra CSS for `flex-fill` won't be needed.

---

**Bootstrap 2 (original 2013 answer)**

Any parent containers also have to be 100% height (html,body and #wrapper). If you make #wrapper {height:100%} and add 'fill-height' to your container it should work. See here:

http://jsfiddle.net/skelly/NyXkt/4/

```
#wrapper {
    min-height: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    margin: 0 auto -33px;
}
```

Comment: This example always seems to have a scrollbar, even if the content is not that big, is that because of the footer?

Comment: Were you ever able to solve the issue with the scrollbar always showing?

Comment: body {overflow:hidden} would fix that, but I'm not sure if that is what you're going for.

Comment: This examples makes entire page scrollable, but would be great to have only the inside in <main> being scrollable.

Comment: Works responsively, simple and clean code.  Great answer!

Comment: Thx, this helped me. Nevertheless I still need the extra css with version 4.3.