# Container vertical align center considering header and footer

Tags: css, alignment

I have code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
 
    }
    
    .container {
        min-height: 200px;
        max-height: 500px;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
          display: flex;
          -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          max-width: 1440px;
          margin: auto;
        
          height: 100%;
    }
    header, footer {
      height: 150px;
      background: #ccc;
    }
    
    footer {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      bottom: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <header></header>
  <div class="container">
    content blah blah blah
  </div>
  <footer>
    fsdfsdfsdfsdfsdffdsadsfasd
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

How I Can vertically align center this container, considering header height and footer (position: absolute and height). I think, what this we can do with display: flex, are how?

I use Bootstrap 3 grid

Example jsbin: http://jsbin.com/timatozuco/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

Here try.. Just configure updated code based on your adjustment..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    html, body {
      height: 100%;

    }

    .container {

          display: -ms-flexbox;
          display: flex;

          top: 10%;
          left: 50%;
          position: absolute;

          box-sizing: border-box;




    }
    header, footer {
      height: 150px;
      background: #ccc;
    }

    footer {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      bottom: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <header></header>
  <div class="container">
    content blah blah blah
  </div>
  <footer>
    fsdfsdfsdfsdfsdffdsadsfasd
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then I guess you want to make the whole container in the center of the page on the basis of header and footer size.

So below code is the solution

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>JS Bin</title>
        <style>
            html, body {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
    
            body {
                font-family: arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
                color: #000;
                line-height: 22px;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
    
            .wrapper {
                width: 100%;
                background: #fff;
                margin: -128px auto 0;
                height: 100%;
                text-align: left;
                clear: both;
                display: table;
                position: relative;
                z-index: 1;
            }
            
            header {
                width: 100%;
                margin: auto;
                background: #ccc;
                height: 66px;
                position: relative;
                z-index: 2;
                border-bottom: 20px solid #fff;
            }
            
            footer {
                background: #ccc;
                width: 100%;
                margin: auto;
                height: 22px;
                clear: both;
                border-top: 20px solid #fff;
                position: relative;
                z-index: 2;
            }
            
            .container {
                vertical-align: middle;
                display: table-cell;
                padding: 128px 0 0;
            }
            
            .container .content {
                text-align: center;
                background: yellow;
                padding: 0 10px;
                width: 300px;
                height: 200px;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <header>
            Header content
        </header>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="content">
                    Container content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            Footer content
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

or you can also visit this link : [Codepen - centered container based on header & footer](https://codepen.io/Adeel91/pen/BdELOY)

Comment: But if I use bootstrap 3, how I Can implement this code?

Comment: well, now this is completely different question and you didn't mention that earlier but in case if you use Bootstrap then may be this might help you out.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641142/bootstrap-fill-fluid-container-between-header-and-footer

Comment: @DronaxD now you added Bootstrap 3 in your question :)