# Bootstrap Navbar and content fill height flexbox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have to create a layout in which a content grid has to be on the full remaining page, but the layout has also a navigation bar.

In order to do this I decided to place the navigation bar in a flex container and the content in a row with height 100%. I need the content to fill the rest of the remaining space. The menu is dynamic so I can not know how the height of the navigation bar is.

However on smaller screens the navigation bar does not resize correctly. If the menu is expanded the menu is overlayed with the content.

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100 d-flex flex-column">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm s-navbar">
     ...
  </nav>
  <div class="row h-100">
     ...// content presented here
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see it here
https://jsfiddle.net/ej9fd368/8/ that the last menu item is cut because of the yellow content.

My requirement is that the content should fill the rest of the page.

Comment: *"The menu is dynamic so I can not know how the height of the navigation bar is."* -- the height of the navbar is always the same 56px. You simply need to take the navbar **out** of your container. Problem solved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Bootstrap 5 (update 2023)**

For future readers, Bootstrap 5 still uses flexbox and the same classes to achieve a full height layout.

https://codeply.com/p/YSZEOQXFh2

**Bootstrap 4 (original answer)**

Instead of using `h-100` on the yellow content area, add an extra CSS class to make it flex-grow:1 in height...

```
.flex-fill {
  flex:1 1 auto;
}
```

https://codeply.com/go/xBAMfbHqbN

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100 d-flex flex-column">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm s-navbar">
        <a class="brand navbar-brand" href="/">Brand</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler s-btn-hamburger order-first s-color-icons" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="navbar-test" aria-label="Toggle navigation" type="button" data-target="#navbar-test" data-toggle="collapse">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon k-icon k-icon-md k-i-hamburger"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse s-menu-content collapse show" id="navbar-test">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown1" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu Item</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown1">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Device">Sub menu</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/Test">Test</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="row flex-fill">
        <main class="col" style="background-color: yellow"></main>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** The `flex-fill` utility class will be included in the next Bootstrap 4.1 release:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/2137d61eacbd962ea41e16a492da8b1d1597d3d9

([Updated **Bootstrap 4.1** demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/dTaVyMah1U))

---

Related question: [How to make the row stretch remaining height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42194886/bs4-a6-how-to-make-the-row-stretch-remaining-height)

Comment: Correct & Clean answer for Bootstrap 4 by Zim here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641142/bootstrap-fill-fluid-container-between-header-and-footer