# Flexbox: stretch sidebar height to the parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

How to properly stretch a child to parent's height? I've tried a lot of variants I found (many quite complicated), but it never worked for me. I would prefer to do this with flex-box, as that seems the newest method. Here is my try:

```
<div class="main h-100">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
    <a href class="navbar-brand">Menu</a>
  </nav>
  <div class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="row h-100">
      <div class="col-xs-2 bg-light h-100 pr-3 menuContainer">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary mt-3 btn-sm btn-block"> Test </button>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light list">
          <ul class="navbar-nav flex-column">
           <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">A1</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">A1</a></li>

          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-10 p-0">
        Content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.bg-light {
  background-color: green !important;
}

.list {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
  align-items:start
}

.menuContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.list {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/2065/

In the end I'd like to remove the scroll, so that the menu (red box) starts where it starts now and ends exactly where the screen end is.

The aim is also to be able to put anything instead of `Content` with `height: 100%` so it does the same.

Both content and menu can be bigger - in that case I expect them to add a scroll on it's own - I use `overflow-y: auto` for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Bootstrap 4.1](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/2137d61eacbd962ea41e16a492da8b1d1597d3d9) there is a `flex-fill` utility class for this purpose.

```
.flex-fill {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

In your case, add it to your `container-fluid` and you won't need all the `h-100`s. Also, make the `container fluid` `d-flex` so that `flex-fill` can also be applied on the `row`.

```
<div class="main h-100 d-flex flex-column">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
    <a href class="navbar-brand">Menu</a>
  </nav>
  <div class="container-fluid flex-fill d-flex">
    <div class="row flex-fill">
      <div class="col-xs-2 bg-light pr-3 menuContainer d-flex flex-column">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary mt-3 btn-sm btn-block"> Test </button>
        <nav class="nav navbar-light list">
          <ul class="navbar-nav flex-column">
           <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">A1</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">A1</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-10 p-0">
        Content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/GEiw0PABgi

Also, note that `col-xs-*` is `col-*` in Bootstrap 4 as the `-xs` infix has been removed. Here's a [simplified example](https://www.codeply.com/go/UJ3cnh0zck) w/o the extra CSS.

Related questions:
[Bootstrap 4 Navbar and content fill height flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191957/bootstrap-4-expanded-navbar-and-content-fill-height-flexbox/49192473)

Comment: You might want to mention that you also added `d-flex flex-column` to `main` element, or else it won't work.

Comment: It also seems that `flex:1 1 auto` would only fill the height if it is a child of a `flex-direction: column`. `flex-direction: row` children are a different story (which I am after)

Comment: Yes, OFC. It fills *height* of flex column, and *width* of flex row. This question is about height so I used `flex-column`.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/2083/

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.bg-light {
  background-color: green !important;
}

.list {
  overflow-y: auto;
  align-items:start
}

.menuContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.list {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

.site-content {
  height: calc(100% - 56px);
}
```

Key differences:

- `flex-direction: column` on sidebar items.
- Remove height 100% on .site-content, instead do `calc(100% - 56px)` which is the header height.

Comment: this doesn't work if the height of the content is greater than the height of the window/sidebar

Answer (score 2):

You're getting an overflow because you're giving many (if not all) of your elements `height: 100%`. It's coming with the Bootstrap code:

```
.h-100 {
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

As a result, when there is more than one element in a container, the siblings overflow the parent.

I would remove `height: 100%` from elements that you want to have fill the height of the container. Flexbox offers a more efficient method.

When you set `display: flex` on an element it applies `align-items: stretch` on the child elements. This means that the children will automatically expand to fill the height of the container.

Set a height on one element (i.e., an ancestor). Then keep adding `display: flex` to each child down the HTML structure. There is no problem nesting flex containers.