# Bootstrap 4 background image full-height with navbar no scrolling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, background-image

I have a page with a navbar.
I want to add a responsive background image to the page (not the navbar).

If I set the page to 100% height it overflows the page with a scrollbar.

How should this be accomplished? I have no idea.

```css
.bg { 
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/350x150");


    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="main-page">
  <div class="bg"></div>
  <div class="data">
    bla bla bla
  </div>

</div>
```

Edit: jsfiddle - [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dzeawubg/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Bootstrap 4 flexbox utils, and add `flex:1 1 auto` to the `main-page` so it fills the height (**with no scrolling**).

https://www.codeply.com/go/isN2cS0m0q

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
<style>
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
.flex-fill {
   flex: 1 1 auto;
}  
.bg { 
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/350x150");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
</style>
<body class="d-flex flex-column">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="main-page d-flex flex-column flex-fill">
    <div class="bg flex-fill"></div>
    <div class="data">
        bla bla bla
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**Note:** The `flex-fill` class will be [included in Bootstrap 4.1](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/2137d61eacbd962ea41e16a492da8b1d1597d3d9) so the extra CSS for `flex-fill` will no longer be needed when 4.1 is released.

---

Related questions:
[Bootstrap 4 Navbar and content fill height flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191957/bootstrap-4-navbar-and-content-fill-height-flexbox)
[Bootstrap 4: How to make the row stretch remaining height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42194886/bootstrap-4-how-to-make-the-row-stretch-remaining-height)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following css rule to your `.bg` class:

```
height: calc(100vh - 56px)
```

That will calculate the height (100% viewport height minus 56px for the height of the navbar).

Working code snippet:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<style>
.bg { 
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/350x150");


    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: calc(100vh - 56px);
}
</style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="main-page">
    <div class="bg"></div>
    <div class="data">
        bla bla bla
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This forces you to rely on the navbar height in two places. If I now change the navbar height, I have to change it here as well