# laravel + bootstrap 4.1: navbar + full height div?

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap

Would like to get a Laravel layout that has Bootstrap 4.1 with navbar and full width + (remaining) height Google map.

Tried using the structure of `Bootstrap 4.1` example from:   [Bootstrap 4 Navbar and content fill height flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191957/bootstrap-4-navbar-and-content-fill-height-flexbox/49192473#49192473)

But unlike the example, when pasting the code inside the `<body>` of a Laravel layout I don't get a navbar + full yellow page. Only the text-lines are yellow.

What is the cleanest way to get navbar + full width+height div (that I plan to use for a Google Map)?

Comment: Can you paste your current code in a codeply?

Comment: I used the Bootstrap 4.1 example from the mentioned link. Direct link: https://www.codeply.com/go/dTaVyMah1U

Comment: In the `app.blade.php` file I removed the default `<body>` content and used that instead. And then use any view to see the result.