# How to automatically adjust row height in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm learning Bootstrap and I'm trying to figure out how to automatically adjust a rows height given this conditions:

- There are 3 rows within a **container-fluid**
- **row1** must adjust to the height of its content
- **row3** must adjust to the height of its content and be at the bottom of the viewport
- **row2** should adjust its height to the space between **row1** and **row3** to fill the **container-fluid**

```css
html, body, .container-fluid {
  height: 100%;
  background: lightyellow;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
}

.content-1 {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

.content-2 {
  height: 200px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

.content-3 {
  height: 25px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="content-1">
      ROW 1 -> Height of its content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="content-2">
      ROW 2 -> Height between row1 and row3 automatically adjusted
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="content-3">
      ROW 3 -> Height of its content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/236844/)

What would be the best approach to do so?. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for the flexbox utility classes. `d-flex` is for `display:flex`, and `flex-grow-1` will make the 2nd child div fill the remaining height. Use `flex-column` as you want a vertical layout.

```
<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="content-1">
      ROW 1 -> Height of its content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row flex-fill">
    <div class="col d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="content-2 h-100">
      ROW 2 -> Height between row1 and row3 automatically adjusted
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="content-3">
      ROW 3 -> Height of its content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/IIVJqGJ2qG

Note: The fixed heights set in the custom CSS have been removed to allow the header/footer to be the height of their content, and the content row to fill the remaining height.

---

Related: 
[Bootstrap 4: How to make the row stretch remaining height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42194886/bootstrap-4-how-to-make-the-row-stretch-remaining-height)
[Bootstrap - Fill fluid container between header and footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641142/)

Answer (score 0):

I see you use bootstrap 4. But anyone who use bootstrap 3 or not at all using any CSS libraries, then the solution would be the code below.

```
.parent-row{
 display: flex;
}
.children-columns{
  display: flex;
}
```