# 100% high div within a twitter bootstrap container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to put a 100% high google map into a Twitter Bootstrap container but it renders as 0px high.

From what I understand from [Twitter Bootstrap: div in container with 100% height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677886/twitter-bootstrap-div-in-container-with-100-height) I added a css class to the container-fluid div with "height: 100%; min-height: 100%;", but it made no difference:

```
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid tall">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
       </div>
...

#map-canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
}

.tall {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: did you also add `html, body { height:100%;}` and also, all the ancestors of map-canvas will need a height set on them - for any percentage heights, you must have a height on all ancestors until a fixed height is found, if no fixed height is found then the percentage heights must go all the way back to the body and html tags

Comment: Good idea @Pete, just tried it, along with also min-height:100%.  No effect though.

Comment: seems to work for me: http://www.bootply.com/RSJVPKBX7T.  Are you sure your tall class does what you think it does?

Comment: I'm not familiar with bootply but I can't see anywhere the bootstrap libraries are being loaded.  Are they in there?

Comment: Bootply automatically includes Bootstrap (just need to pick the version)

Comment: Thanks @ZimSystem.

Comment: Hi there. Just checking if your problem was successfully solved? If so, can you please pick one of the answers to mark as correct; this prevents this question from showing up on the 'Unanswered' tab. If not, can you please list any problems you're still facing, so that I can try to help you further. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I /think/ I may have sorted this out, based on Pete's comments (so really this is /his/ answer.)

It seems that /every/ element down to the map container requires the tall class, and the map container itself requires "height: 100%; min-height: 600px;", something like:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.tall {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#map-canvas {
...
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 600px;
}
```

Not sure if this is a bootstrap requirement or a google maps one.

(I did put a comment in the OP warning that I was not a CSS guru, but someone removed it.  I apologise if the absence of that mislead anyone into thinking I knew what I was doing.)

Answer (score 1):

You're using the CSS ID selector `#tall`, but specifying a *class* of tall in the HTML. You'll need to change `#tall` to `.tall` in the CSS.

I was also messing around with CodePen, and it would seem that you need to *either* specify a `#map-canvas` height based on the height of the window (vh), *or* specify a height for all parent divs up to and *including* the div where you specify the fixed height that you want the map to occupy. Note that `margin-bottom` won't effect `#map-canvas`, and that you don't need to specify a `minimum-height`.

Check out the CodePen below for an implementation showcasing how a parent div can specify the height of the map. The map div has a height and width of 100% of the parent, and will adapt accordingly:

http://codepen.io/Obsidian-Age/pen/AXzXzv

Comment: Good catch.  That makes me feel stoopid :)  Regrettably though it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: I've updated my answer, and it should hopefully now solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code to be similar to the code below:
HTML change to:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
       </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and css change to

```
#map-canvas {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
}
```

here is a preview:

http://codepen.io/mhadaily/pen/RRdXpY

Comment: Thanks Majid.  That doesn't work with a Bootstrap container though.

Comment: please have a look http://codepen.io/mhadaily/pen/RRdXpY , it can be applied to bootstrap as well. no worries. check the link out.