# How to make the row stretch remaining height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I'm trying to make the `container-fluid` and 2nd `row` to stretch to the remaining height but I couldn't find a way to do it.

I have tried setting the `align-items/align-self` to `stretch` but didn't work either.

Below is my code structure:

```
<div class="container-fluid"> <!-- I want this container to stretch to the height of the parent -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h5>Header</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row"> <!-- I want this row height to filled the remaining height -->
        <widgets [widgets]="widgets" class="hing"></widgets>
        <div class="col portlet-container portlet-dropzone"> <!-- if row is not the right to stretch the remaining height, this column also fine -->
            <template row-host></template>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using **Bootstrap 4 A6**. Could someone suggest me how to make the container and the row to stretch the remaining height?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Bootstrap 4.1.0 has a utility class for `flex-grow` which it what you need for the row to fill the remaining height. You can add a custom "fill" class for this. You also have to make sure the container is full height.

The class name in Bootstrap 4.1 is `flex-grow-1`

```html
<style>
html,body{
    height:100%;
}

.flex-fill {
    flex:1;
}
</style>

<div class="container-fluid d-flex h-100 flex-column">
    <!-- I want this container to stretch to the height of the parent -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h5>Header</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bg-light flex-fill d-flex justify-content-start">
        <!-- I want this row height to filled the remaining height -->
        <div class="col portlet-container portlet-dropzone">
            <!-- if row is not the right to stretch the remaining height, this column also fine -->
            Content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/gfitG8PkNE

Related: [Bootstrap 4 make nested row fill parent that has been made to fill viewport height using flex-grow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48927663/make-a-nested-row-fill-its-parent-that-has-been-made-to-fill-viewport-height-usi/48929133#48929133)

Comment: Just a question why would we need `align-items-stretch align-content-stretch` both here?

Comment: Actually neither one is needed

Comment: im not sure you need flex-fill and d-flex on that 2nd row. h-100 should suffice..one less custom style in the CSS.