# How can I make Bootstrap 4 columns have a height of 100%?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, grid-layout

how can I make a column take up 100% height of the browser w bootstrap 4?

See the following: https://codepen.io/johnpickly/pen/dRqxjV

Note the yellow div, I need this div/column to take up a height of 100%... Is there way to make this happen without having to make all parent div's have a height of 100%?

Thank you

html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">

    <div class="col-4 hidden-md-down" id="yellow">
      XXXX
    </div>

    <div class="col-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-8">
      Form Goes Here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm assuming you've specified this somewhere: `<div class="col-sm-2 hidden-lg-up hidden-xs-down"></div>`?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Use the Bootstrap 4 `h-100` class for `height:100%;`

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
  <div class="row justify-content-center h-100">
    <div class="col-4 hidden-md-down" id="yellow">
      XXXX
    </div>
    <div class="col-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-8">
      Form Goes Here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/zxd6oN1yWp

You'll also need ensure any parent(s) are also 100% height (or have a defined height)...

```
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Note: 100% height is not the same as "remaining" height.

---

**Related:** [Bootstrap 4: How to make the row stretch remaining height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42194886/bootstrap-4-how-to-make-the-row-stretch-remaining-height/42195475#42195475)

Comment: This doesn't work if the content in the col is bigger than 100% height - like long forms.

Comment: Yeah, in that case you'd use min-height instead: https://www.codeply.com/go/MjGkqFWmA1

Comment: Instead to edit the css file, add `<html class="h-100">` and `<body class="h-100">`

Comment: @Zim, In case, if I have more than 3 parents then I have to add h-100 class to all the parents?

Answer (score 27):

Use bootstrap class **vh-100**

for exp:

```
   <div class="vh-100">
       <p> Full Height </p>
   </div>
```

Comment: wow, spent days on this, ty.

Answer (score 10):

I have tried over a half-dozen solutions suggested on Stack Overflow, and the only thing that worked for me was this:

```
<div class="row" style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        Column A
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        Column B
    </div>
</div>
```

I got the solution from https://codepen.io/ondrejsvestka/pen/gWPpPo

Note that it seems to affect the column margins. I had to apply adjustments to those.

Comment: Unfortunately, I just discovered that this causes the columns to stack vertically in Safari.  Leaving this here in case someone knows how to fix that.

Comment: wouldn't that just be caused by the `flex-wrap: wrap` ? Basically means if the screen doesn't have the real-estate to put them together, it'll wrap to the next line, making it below instead of beside.

Answer (score 2):

*I came across this problem because my cols exceeded the row grid length (> 12)*

A solution using 100% Bootstrap 4:

Since the rows in Bootstrap are already `display: flex`

You just need to add `flex-fill` to the Col, and `h-100` to the container and any children.

Pen here: https://codepen.io/joshkopecek/pen/Exjdgjo

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
  <div class="row justify-content-center h-100">

    <div class="col-4 hidden-md-down flex-fill" id="yellow">
      XXXX
    </div>

    <div id="blue" class="col-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-8 h-100">
      Form Goes Here
    </div>

    <div id="green" class="col-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-8 h-100">
      Another form
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this like this:

```
    <section className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row justify-content-center">

                <article className="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center vh-100">
                        <!-- content -->
                </article>

            </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `display: table` for **parent div** and `display: table-cell` for **children divs**

HTML :

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row justify-content-center display-as-table">

    <div class="col-4 hidden-md-down" id="yellow">
      XXXX<br />
      XXXX<br />
      XXXX<br />
      XXXX<br />
      XXXX<br />
      XXXX<br />vv
      XXXX<br />
    </div>

    <div class="col-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-8" id="red">
      Form Goes Here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#yellow {
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  width: 50%;
}
#red {background: red}

.container-fluid {bacgkround: #ccc}

/* this is the part make equal height */
.display-as-table {display: table; width: 100%;}
.display-as-table > div {display: table-cell; float: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

see documentation booot [Bootstrap sizing # Relative to the parent](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/sizing/#relative-to-the-parent)

```
<div class="h-100 d-inline-block">
     <p> Full Height </p>
</div>
```