# Bootstrap 4 - Full height

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I know there are many threads about this but I tried everything from the other threads and it didn't work.

So I currently have this code right here:

```html
<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column" style="height: 100vh;">
  <div class="row d-flex flex-column no-gutters">
    <app-top class="col"></app-top>

    <div class="row flex-row no-gutters" style="margin-top: 38px;">
      <app-left class="col flex-shrink-0"></app-left>

      <div class="col">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>

      <app-right class="col flex-shrink-0"></app-right>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The content isn't stretching how I would like it to.
There is a Navbar at the top and then there should be three columns, with full height.

Comment: can we have any content in there?

Comment: You need to use `flex-fill` or `flex-grow-1`: https://www.codeply.com/go/wq0yGMndc8

Answer (score 1):

Remove styles 100vh from the div and add bootstrap 4 class for 100% height

```
<div class="h-100"></div>
```

Comment: I don't know why you had a negative vote, but this worked perfect for me. So thumbs up for you.

Answer (score 1):

This Should Do It. Avoid using inline styles.

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
```

Similar answer Here: [Bootstrap 4, how to make a col have a height of 100%?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44982624/bootstrap-4-how-to-make-a-col-have-a-height-of-100)