# flex-grow-1 not working in some versions of bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

`flex-grow-1` is working with if use bootstrap 4.1.3 copied from [w3school sample](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_flex-grow&stacked=h)

```html
<head>
  <!-- flex-grow-1 is working with these libraries -->
  <!------------------------------------------------->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container mt-3">
    <div class="d-flex mb-3">
      <div class="p-2 bg-info">Flex item 1</div>
      <div class="p-2 flex-grow-1 bg-primary">Flex item 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

But if I used bootstrap 4.0.0 CDNs that are provided in [Bootstrap 4 official page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/), then `flex-grow-1` class does not work - seems that the class not exists:

```html
<head>
  <!-- flex-grow-1 is not working with these libraries -->
  <!----------------------------------------------------->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container mt-3">
    <div class="d-flex mb-3">
      <div class="p-2 bg-info">Flex item 1</div>
      <div class="p-2 flex-grow-1 bg-primary">Flex item 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

### Questions:

1. Is this a bug? Or am I making a mistake?
2. The reason I am reluctant to use Bootstrap version 4.1.3 CDN is that they don't have the `integrity` and `crossorigin` security fields. Is there any CDN for version 4.1.3 which does have these security fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug. As you can [see here](https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2018/04/09/bootstrap-4-1/) the `.flex-fill`, `.flex-grow-*`, and `.flex-shrink-*` utilities weren't added until **Bootstrap 4.1**.

Related:
[Bootstrap 4 make nested row fill parent that has been made to fill viewport height using flex-grow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48927663/)
[Bootstrap 4 - Sticky footer - Dynamic footer height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45912296/bootstrap-4-sticky-footer-dynamic-footer-height)

Answer (score 0):

The CDNs are on [Bootstrap 4.1 page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/download/).