# Bootstrap 4 row fill remaining height

Tags: html, css, grid, bootstrap-4, row

I'm struggling to make the a row stretch to fill the rest of the available height. I tried adding `h-100` to the row class but that causes a white space at the bottom of the screen. There must be a way to do it but I'm totally stumped.. Here is my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
  <div class="row justify-content-center h-100">
    <div class="col-4 bg-red">
      <div class="h-100">
        <div class="row justify-content-center bg-purple">
          <div class="text-white">
            <div style="height:200px">ROW 1</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center bg-blue">
          <div class="text-white">ROW 2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8 bg-gray"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/ee92/pen/zjpjXW/?editors=1100

[image]

I'd like to make the the blue row (ROW 2) fill all the red space. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Use the [Bootstrap 4.1 `flex-grow-1`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#grow-and-shrink) class...

https://codeply.com/go/Iyjsd8djnz

```css
html,body{height:100%;}

.bg-purple {
  background: rgb(48,0,50);
}
.bg-gray {
  background: rgb(74,74,74);
}
.bg-blue {
  background: rgb(50,101,196);
}
.bg-red {
  background: rgb(196,50,53);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid h-100">
  <div class="row justify-content-center h-100">
    <div class="col-4 bg-red">
      <div class="h-100 d-flex flex-column">
        <div class="row justify-content-center bg-purple">
          <div class="text-white">
            <div style="height:150px">ROW 1 - fixed height</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center bg-blue flex-grow-1">
          <div class="text-white">ROW 2 - grow remaining height</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8 bg-gray"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update 4.3.1:** Another example using the vh-100 utility class

https://codeply.com/go/h3bZbM6eSS

```css
.bg-purple {
  background: rgb(48,0,50);
}
.bg-gray {
  background: rgb(74,74,74);
}
.bg-blue {
  background: rgb(50,101,196);
}
.bg-red {
  background: rgb(196,50,53);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row justify-content-center min-vh-100">
    <div class="col-4 bg-red">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
        <div class="row justify-content-center bg-purple">
          <div class="text-white">
            <div style="height:150px">ROW 1 - fixed height</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center bg-blue flex-grow-1">
          <div class="text-white">ROW 2 - grow remaining height</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8 bg-gray"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Related: [How to make the row stretch remaining height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42194886)

Comment: Everything it's great until the text from first row starting to grow and hiding under second row.. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/maVoKy :/

Comment: @Nate Did You look at [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/maVoKy) I attached? Anyway in my case setting fixed height is not a option..

Comment: What browser are you using? In chrome, your first row exceeds the height of the screen for me, but it doesn't "hide" under the second row -- instead it pushes the second row off-screen. On Safari it hides underneath the second row, which feels more appropriate than what chrome does. What exactly are you looking to achieve? I, too, didn't want a fixed height, but I knew it was small enough that it would fit inside of my expected minimum height. I think in this problem domain you have a row you know is "small" and then the other should expand to remaining space. That isn't what you want?

Comment: @Nate as `ROW 1` has a fixed height in this answer it shouldnt grow but the content should overflow to the right or bottom.

Comment: @C4d I understand. I removed the fixed height from row 1 in my usage, because I wanted two rows to consume the entire space, but the first row to be minimal. It sounded like `m1l05z` wanted the same. Perhaps this wasn't the best solution for my problem, but it's what I found =).

Comment: What if row2 displays a long list, and wanted to have it stick to whatever height remaining, and not grow to the end of the list.

Answer (score 7):

This is a solution. The wrapper `div` has to have h-100, the `div` that adapts to height has to have flex-grow-1 and overflow-auto. This way, the `div` will grow to fill the space when its content is minor than the available space and will show the scrollbar when its content is higher than the available space.

[Demo jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alesoftjab/uwxhbor6/14/)

```
<div class="h-100 d-flex flex-column bg-yellow px-2">
<div class="flex-column justify-content-center bg-purple px-2">        
    <div class="text-white p-0" style="height:50px">HEADER</div>
</div>

<div class="flex-column justify-content-center bg-red text-white px-2 flex-grow-1 overflow-auto">

        <div>Item1</div>
        <div>Item2</div>
        INNER text 1<br>
        INNER text 2<br>

</div>

<div class="flex-column justify-content-center bg-darkblue px-2">
    <div class="text-white p-0" style="height:50px">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. This solved my problem. Can you also tell how can I achieve the same with two columns? I want to have ColumnA and columnB, both should adapt to the height and scroll independently of each other.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone has tired of getting this to work, here is a super easy solution which will work in most scenarios. Just add the below class to the div for which you are trying to fill the remaining height:
Please note that 100vh is 100% of visible height and 200px is the total fixed height of the remainging divs above.

```
.fillRemaining {
height: calc(100vh - 200px);
}
```