# Ionic 4 ion-row fill remaining height

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

How to annotate an `ion-row` so that it fills the remaining space?

For the following example the yellow row "Content" should expand until all the remaining (green) space is taken.

```
<ion-grid style="background-color: green; height: 100%;">
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col text-center style="background-color: purple;">
      <p>Example text</p>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

  <ion-row>
    <ion-col text-center style="background-color: yellow">
      <p>Content</p>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

  <ion-row>
    <ion-col text-center style="background-color: blue;">
      <p>Example text</p>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

[image: Colorful row example]

A similar question was asked for Bootstrap and got solved with flex-grow. See: [Bootstrap 4 row fill remaining height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50262517/bootstrap-4-row-fill-remaining-height)

But can we stretch the row while sticking to th row/col syntax and not introduce more flexboxes?

Answer (score 23):

It is possible to annotate the grid container with `display: flex; flex-flow: column` and the stretching row with `flex-grow: 1`.

```
<ion-grid style="background-color: green; height: 100%; display: flex; flex-flow: column;">
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col text-center style="background-color: purple;">
      <p>Example text</p>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

  <ion-row style="flex-grow: 1;">
    <ion-col text-center style="background-color: yellow">
      <p>Content</p>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

  <ion-row>
    <ion-col text-center style="background-color: blue;">
      <p>Example text</p>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Then it will look like this:
[image: solution]

When the grid compressed (instead of stretched), the rows are moving inside each other. To prevent this use `flex-shrink: 0;` on every row.

Comment: In case they are better ways of doing it, I would be happy to upvote/accept those. Because my solution is putting a `display:flex` onto the grid.

Comment: Salutes to you for not keeping the answer to yourself but putting it out there.