# make one of bootstrap rows fill the rest of the height in view and scrollable

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Basically, I have a bootstrap container and 2 rows in it, one being the header and the other the content. I would like to have the container to have the height of the viewport so that the content is scrollable.

```
<div class="container-fluid overflow-hidden h-100">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h1>Header</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row content-area">
        <div class="col">
            <div>Content blah...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.content-area {
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

The `max-height` renders the content full height of the parent which is the container so a part of the content is chopped off the view. I would like the content to fill the rest of the container's height.

I tried `flex-grow-1` from bootstrap instead of the css height but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the container `vh-100 d-flex flex-column` and then add `flex-grow-1` to the row.

```
<div class="container-fluid overflow-hidden vh-100 d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h1>Header</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row content-area bg-info flex-grow-1">
        <div class="col">
            <h1>Content blah... </h1>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/7u2lXo0jyG

Related: [Bootstrap 4 row fill remaining height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50262517/bootstrap-4-row-fill-remaining-height/50262611#50262611)

Answer (score 1):

Add vh-100 class on the first row. It will make the viewport height, 100%.

```
<div class="container-fluid overflow-hidden h-100">
<div class="row vh-100">
    <div class="col">
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row content-area">
    <div class="col">
        <div>Content blah...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Source: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/sizing/

Comment: Thank you but my question was how to make the 2nd row fill the rest of the viewport height and still scrollable?