# Make row occupy full height in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to create a Bootstrap grid whose second row occupies the full height of the page, in a very similar fashion to [Twitter bootstrap 3 two columns full height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089384/twitter-bootstrap-3-two-columns-full-height). However, the "non-hacky" answer provided, which uses Bootstrap 4's `h-100`, doesn't seem to be working. Here's the code and its output:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="wiewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
    html {
        height: 100%;
    }
    body {
        min-height: 100%;
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
    main {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    #second-row {
        background-color: green;
    }
    textarea {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <main class="container-fluid h-100">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                  Hello,
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                  World!
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row h-100" id="second-row">
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <textarea></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <textarea></textarea>
              </div>
          </div>
      </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Output of the code]

Update: [Bootstrap 4: How to make the row stretch remaining height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42194886/bootstrap-4-how-to-make-the-row-stretch-remaining-height/42195475#42195475), a similar question, has an answer that uses Bootstrap 4's `flex-grow` class. I tried it like so:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="wiewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
    html {
        height: 100%;
    }
    body {
        min-height: 100%;
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
    main {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    #second-row {
        background-color: green;
    }
    textarea {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <main class="container-fluid d-flex h-100 flex-column">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                  Hello,
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                  World!
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row flex-fill d-flex justify-content-start" id="second-row">
              <div class="col-sm-8 portlet-container portlet-dropzone">
                  <textarea></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-4 portlet-container portlet-dropzone">
                  <textarea></textarea>
              </div>
          </div>
      </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Output remains unchanged.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should use `flex-grow:1;` as explained in the other answer: [Bootstrap 4: How to make the row stretch remaining height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42194886)

The problem is that body should be `height:100%;` not `min-height`...

```
<main class="container-fluid d-flex h-100 flex-column">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
          Hello,
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
          World!
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row flex-grow-1" id="second-row">
      <div class="col-sm-8 portlet-container portlet-dropzone">
          <textarea></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 portlet-container portlet-dropzone">
          <textarea></textarea>
      </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/tpecZ31njp